# Esper: about the @Hint("reclaim_group_aged=age_in_seconds")

Tags: esper, hint

In Esper doc 5.6.2.1 Hints Pertaining to Group-By,
as it say:
"As the engine has no means of detecting when aggregation state (sums per symbol) can be
discarded, you may use the following hints to control aggregation state lifetime.

The @Hint("reclaim_group_aged=age_in_seconds") hint instructs the engine to discard

### aggregation state that has not been updated for age_in_seconds seconds."

how understand "aggregation state"? if some epl didn't updated events, will these events be removed or droped?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the doc what you are quoting is only when there are no data windows, i.e. "select sum(xyz) from ABC group by somekey". Since there are no data windows in this query, this aggregates all ABC events that arrived since start. Aggregation state in this example is the total (sum) per group. In this no-data-window aggregation with group-by when for a given value of "somekey" no data has arrived for N seconds the engine can be instructed to discard/forget that total and "somekey" value.